# How can I solve ReferenceError: $ is not defined, on Remote server?

Tags: jquery, laravel

In a Laravel app I am running I suddenly get a remote error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ https/ ... edit_profile.php:2:1
```

The application used to run smoothly.
Locally the app still works fine, it is when I push it to production that I get the error.

Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong?
I am afraid to break something at the remote serverside

```
<script>
$( 'button' ).click(function(){
   $( '#file_picture_input' ).click(); 
});

$( '#file_picture_input').change(function(){
   $( 'span' ).text($( this ).val() ); 
});
</script>
```

The view it refres to is edit_profile:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('header')
    @include('includes.basic_header')
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="container minigame-container">
        <div class="row minigame-text-row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                @if (!$valid)
                    <p><b>{{ __('Welcome at Detective Collective!') }}</b><p>
                    
                    <p>{{ __('Before you begin with solving crimes, you first need to finish your profile.') }}</p>
                @endif
            </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="row minigame-text-row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h5 class="header_dark">{{ __('My Profile') }}</h5>
                <form method='POST' id="account_form" runat="server" action="profile/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <h6 class="red">{{ $error }}</h6>
                    @endforeach
                    <b>{{ __('Profile photo') }}</b>

                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script src="{{ url('js/cropimage.js') }}" ></script>

@stop


@section('footer')
    @include('includes.basic_footer')
@stop

<script>
$( 'button' ).click(function(){
   $( '#file_picture_input' ).click(); 
});

$( '#file_picture_input').change(function(){
   $( 'span' ).text($( this ).val() ); 
});
</script>
```

jquery is pulled in by bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Comment: it means jQuery is undefined at the time your `$(..)` is executing. So there is probably an issue with the order of the scripts.

Comment: Yet, it runs fine at localhost... So the orfer is fine there?

Comment: What can it be then? Something with the remote jquery installation? How can I check that? Or is jquery not correctly pulled in?

Comment: Check jqueryis  loaded in the network tab? It sounds like it is not loaded by the time you run the script.

Comment: Probelem went away.. Does not reproduce. can you understand that?

Comment: The only error I find is: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://cluego.nl/js/bootstrap.esm.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Added document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ()  {} around the jquery, jsut ot be sure, as some else suggested...

Comment: if the problem went away, that probably means that it is depending on network speed and whether jQuery happens to load sooner or later (which again is something you have to look into). You should look at the spots where jQuery is loaded and where your own script is loaded, then check the `<script>` tag for any attributes like `defer` or `async`.